# How genrics work in java at run time?

Tags: java

I encounter an intresting issue, I am getting raw list from some third party API call which is containing CustomObject in it, and I keep that list in to genric list of type String.

```
List<String> strList = getCustomObjectList();//This is third part API
which resturn raw List
```

Now I would like to get list element

```
String myStrValue = strList.get(0);
```

here I am getting  below exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.some.CustomObject cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String

Now I am curious to know 2 things

1. Genrics is compile time type checking concept, then how it throws exception at run time?
2. How run time type casting is done in such scenario?

Comment: 1. You were warned about the unchecked assignment.

Comment: 2. The compiler will do a cast: `String myStrValue = (String)strList.get(0);`

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your help comment, Eran answers and your commant helps me to understand this.

Comment: If the third party API returns a raw `List` this code should not compile.

Comment: @EJP [why wouldn't it compile?](https://ideone.com/xIgbXw)

Comment: https://medium.com/@saha.tushar091/java-generics-cheat-sheet-2b178948233 you may refer this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In compile time, the compiler gives you a warning about the unsafe assignment you are making (assigning a raw `List` to a `List<String>` variable), but the assignment is accepted for backwards compatibility (the 3rd party API that contains the `getCustomObjectList()` method may have been written before generics were introduced in Java 5).

In run-time `strList.get(0)` returns an `Object`, but that `Object` is cast to `String` due to the `List<String>` type of `strList`. The code that performs the casting is added by the compiler at compile time, but only during run-time the casting is performed, and the exception is thrown if the run-time type of `strList.get(0)` is not `String`.

Comment: yes getCustomObjectList() API were written before java 5, Anyways good explanation.